# calico-kube-controllers and calico-node are not ready (CrashLoopBackOff)

Tags: kubernetes, calico, kubespray

I deployed a brand new k8s cluster using kubespray, everything works fine but all of the calico related pods are not ready. And after many hours of debugging I couldn't find the reason why calico pods are crashing. I even disabled/stopped the entire firewalld service but nothing changed.

One other important thing is that `calicoctl node status` output is not stable and every time gets called show something different:

```
Calico process is not running.
```

```
Calico process is running.

None of the BGP backend processes (BIRD or GoBGP) are running.
```

```
Calico process is running.

IPv4 BGP status
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
|  PEER ADDRESS  |     PEER TYPE     | STATE |  SINCE   |  INFO   |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+
| 192.168.231.42 | node-to-node mesh | start | 06:23:41 | Passive |
+----------------+-------------------+-------+----------+---------+

IPv6 BGP status
No IPv6 peers found.
```

Another log that shown up often is the following message:

```
bird: Unable to open configuration file /etc/calico/confd/config/bird.cfg: No such file or directory
bird: Unable to open configuration file /etc/calico/confd/config/bird6.cfg: No such file or directory
```

Also tried changing IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD with each of the following but nothing changed:

```
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=can-reach=www.google.com
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=can-reach=8.8.8.8
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=eth1
kubectl set env daemonset/calico-node -n kube-system IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD=interface=eth.*
```

### Expected Behavior

All pods, daemonset, deployment and replicaset related to calico should be in READY state.

### Current Behavior

All pods, daemonset, deployment and replicaset related to calico is in NOT READY state.

### Possible Solution

Nothing yet, I am asking for help on how to debug / overcome this issue.

### Steps to Reproduce (for bugs)

Its the latest version of kubespray with the following Context & Environment.

```
git reflog

7e4b176 HEAD@{0}: clone: from https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray.git
```

### Context

I'm trying to deploy a k8s cluster which has one master and one worker node. Also note that the servers taking part in this cluster are located in an almost airgapped/offline enviroment with limited access to global internet, of course the ansible process of deploying cluster using kubespray was successful but I'm facing this issue with calico pods.

### Your Environment

```
cat inventory/mycluster/hosts.yaml

all:
  hosts:
    node1:
      ansible_host: 192.168.231.41
      ansible_port: 32244
      ip: 192.168.231.41
      access_ip: 192.168.231.41
    node2:
      ansible_host: 192.168.231.42
      ansible_port: 32244
      ip: 192.168.231.42
      access_ip: 192.168.231.42
  children:
    kube_control_plane:
      hosts:
        node1:
    kube_node:
      hosts:
        node1:
        node2:
    etcd:
      hosts:
        node1:
    k8s_cluster:
      children:
        kube_control_plane:
        kube_node:
    calico_rr:
      hosts: {}
```

```
calicoctl version

Client Version:    v3.19.2
Git commit:        6f3d4900
Cluster Version:   v3.19.2
Cluster Type:      kubespray,bgp,kubeadm,kdd,k8s
```

```
cat /etc/centos-release

CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
```

```
uname -r

3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64
```

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.4", GitCommit:"3cce4a82b44f032d0cd1a1790e6d2f5a55d20aae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-11T18:16:05Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.4", GitCommit:"3cce4a82b44f032d0cd1a1790e6d2f5a55d20aae", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-08-11T18:10:22Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.7", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

```
 kubectl get nodes -o wide

NAME    STATUS   ROLES                  AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION                CONTAINER-RUNTIME
node1   Ready    control-plane,master   19h   v1.21.4   192.168.231.41   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.8
node2   Ready    <none>                 19h   v1.21.4   192.168.231.42   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1160.42.2.el7.x86_64   docker://20.10.8
```

```
kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide

NAMESPACE     NAME                                           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP               NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system   pod/calico-kube-controllers-8575b76f66-57zw4   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   327        19h   192.168.231.42   node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/calico-node-4hkzb                          0/1     Running            245        14h   192.168.231.42   node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/calico-node-hznhc                          0/1     Running            245        14h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-8474476ff8-b6lqz                   1/1     Running            0          19h   10.233.96.1      node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-8474476ff8-gdkml                   1/1     Running            0          19h   10.233.90.1      node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/dns-autoscaler-7df78bfcfb-xnn4r            1/1     Running            0          19h   10.233.90.2      node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-node1                       1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-node1              1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-dmw22                           1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-wzpnv                           1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.42   node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-node1                       1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/nginx-proxy-node2                          1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.42   node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/nodelocaldns-6h5q2                         1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.42   node2   <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/nodelocaldns-7fwbd                         1/1     Running            0          19h   192.168.231.41   node1   <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE     NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE   SELECTOR
default       service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.233.0.1   <none>        443/TCP                  19h   <none>
kube-system   service/coredns      ClusterIP   10.233.0.3   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   19h   k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE   CONTAINERS    IMAGES                                     SELECTOR
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node    2         2         0       2            0           kubernetes.io/os=linux   19h   calico-node   quay.io/calico/node:v3.19.2                k8s-app=calico-node
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy     2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   19h   kube-proxy    k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.21.4              k8s-app=kube-proxy
kube-system   daemonset.apps/nodelocaldns   2         2         2       2            2           kubernetes.io/os=linux   19h   node-cache    k8s.gcr.io/dns/k8s-dns-node-cache:1.17.1   k8s-app=nodelocaldns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                      READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS                IMAGES                                                       SELECTOR
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers   0/1     1            0           19h   calico-kube-controllers   quay.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.19.2                      k8s-app=calico-kube-controllers
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                   2/2     2            2           19h   coredns                   k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.0                            k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system   deployment.apps/dns-autoscaler            1/1     1            1           19h   autoscaler                k8s.gcr.io/cpa/cluster-proportional-autoscaler-amd64:1.8.3   k8s-app=dns-autoscaler

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                 DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS                IMAGES                                                       SELECTOR
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-kube-controllers-8575b76f66   1         1         0       19h   calico-kube-controllers   quay.io/calico/kube-controllers:v3.19.2                      k8s-app=calico-kube-controllers,pod-template-hash=8575b76f66
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-8474476ff8                   2         2         2       19h   coredns                   k8s.gcr.io/coredns/coredns:v1.8.0                            k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=8474476ff8
kube-system   replicaset.apps/dns-autoscaler-7df78bfcfb            1         1         1       19h   autoscaler                k8s.gcr.io/cpa/cluster-proportional-autoscaler-amd64:1.8.3   k8s-app=dns-autoscaler,pod-template-hash=7df78bfcfb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fortunately increasing `timeoutSeconds` for both `livenessProbe` & `readinessProbe` from **1** to **60** fixes the issue.

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system daemonset.apps/calico-node
kubectl edit -n kube-system deployment.apps/calico-kube-controllers
```

https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/issues/4935

Comment: This didn't work for me using MicroK8s with a worker on a different VM on the same private network.

Comment: did you get the issue fixed on microk8s  @AnisBenna

Comment: Yes actually, by doing a monkey patch. See https://github.com/canonical/microk8s/issues/2402#issuecomment-950884240

Comment: This didn't work for me either.